# Kendo grid keeps spinning

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm doing something that should be rather simply with a Kendo UI grid. I have the following Javascript in my web page:

```
<div id="venueSelectGrid"></div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        model.Init();

    });

    var model = function () {

        Init = function () {

        gridSelect('#venueSelectGrid', 'VenueID', 'VenueName', 'Venue', 'DataManager/GetVenue');

    };

    return {
        Init: Init
    };
}();

</script>
```

The gridSelect function is defined in another js file as follows:

```
gridSelect = function (name, idColumnName, descColumnName, descColumnTitle, url) {

$(name).kendoGrid({
    autoBind: true,
    width: "18em",
    height: "16em",
    columns: [
        {
            field: "IsChecked",
            title: "<input type='checkbox' name='IsChecked'  class='centerCheckbox parentCheckbox' />",
            template: "<input type='checkbox' name='IsChecked' class='childCheckbox' />",
            headerTemplate: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onclick='checkAll(this)'/>",
            //headerTemplate: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onclick='checkAll(" + name + ", this)'/>",
            width: "2em"
        },
        {
            field: idColumnName
        },
        {
            field: descColumnName,
            title: descColumnTitle,
            width: "15em"
        }
    ],
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 0
    }),
    //selectable: "row",
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: false,
    reorderable: false,
    resizable: false,
    columnMenu: false,
}).data("kendoGrid").hideColumn(idColumnName);
```

};

The data controller shows below executes just fine:

```
public ActionResult GetVenue()
{
    JsonResult jsonResult = Json(_DictionaryRepository.GetVenue("1"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return jsonResult;
}
```

which returns a nicely instantiated POCO object containing the VenueID and the VenueName.

The problem is when the page displays the Wait spinner displays and keeps going. No data ever appears. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult GetVenue([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    JsonResult jsonResult = Json(_DictionaryRepository.GetVenue("1").ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsonResult;
}
```